# Ejecutar otro case del switch dada cierta condición en un if

Tags: c++

Lo que pasa, sintetizando, es que necesito que en el case 1 cuando se cumpla la condicion de `if (condicional =='y')` que ese caracter lo ingresa el usuario, quiero invocar o que se ejecute el case 2. ¿Se puede hacer?

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"Presione segun sea su requerimiento: "<<endl;
    cout<<" 1 = consultar cantidad y precio de asignturas de este semestre"<<endl;
    cout<<" 2 = calcular su promedio y saber si aplica para incentivo academico"<<endl;
    cin>>numero;cout<<endl;
    cout<<"******************************************"<<endl;
    switch (numero){
    case 1:
         cout <<"En este semestre se esta cursando actualmente 3 materias"<<endl;
         cout <<"Cada materia tiene un coste de: 50000"<<endl;
         cout <<"******************************************"<<endl;
            cout<<"Si desea calcular su promedio presione: "<<endl;
            cout<<"y"<<endl;
            cout<<"Si desea salir del programa presione: "<<endl;
            cout<<"n"<<endl;
            cin>>condicional;
            if (condicional=='y'){
                numero = 2;
                }
            else if (condicional =='n'){
               return 0;
            }
            else { cout<<"Opcion invalida";}



    case 2:
         cout <<"Bienvenido a continuacion podra calcular su promedio "<< endl;

         notasEstudiante (n1,n2,n3);

         if (promedio>=4.5){
         descuento = (precioAsignaturas * 30 / 100);
         precioFinal = (precioAsignaturas - descuento);
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando lo compilo y ejecuto ocurre esto:

```
Presione segun sea su requerimiento:
 1 = consultar cantidad y precio de asignturas de este semestre
 2 = calcular su promedio y saber si aplica para incentivo academico
1

******************************************
En este semestre se esta cursando actualmente 3 materias
Cada materia tiene un coste de: 50000
******************************************
Si desea calcular su promedio presione:
y
Si desea salir del programa presione:
n
y

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.675 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Le doy a la 'y' pero se me finaliza el programa, cosa que ya lo tengo configurado con el 'n', entonces necesito que cuando presione la 'y' se empiece a ejecutar el case 2.

Comment: Primero, decirte que una de las normas del sitio es que el código se pegue como texto y no como imagen. Las imágenes son difíciles de leer para algunas personas y en algunos dispositivos, y no permiten a quien te quiera ayudar que pueda copiar el código para probarlo. Puedes editar la pregunta para quitar la imagen y poner en su lugar el fuente del programa o un fragmento. Ponle una línea con ``` delante y otra al final para que salga correctamente formateado.

Comment: Respecto a la pregunta, no se puede desde una rama del switch saltar a otra cambiando el valor de la variable de switch, ya que ésta se evalúa una sola vez. Lo que sí puedes aprovechar es el hecho de que después de terminar con el código de una rama del switch, el programa continuará con el código de la rama siguiente, a menos que lo evites con un break. Así que puedes reescribir tu condicional para que no haga el break en el caso de que quieras "saltar" al caso 2. Eso solo te sirve si el caso 2 es el siguiente al 1.

Comment: @abulafia te agradezco mucho tanto la recomendación para futuras publicaciones y la respuesta del problema, ambas serán implementadas. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Eh, nada de futuras publicaciones :-) Si puedes arregla esta ya, si no quieres que te la terminen cerrando

Comment: @abulafia Dale dale, voy voy jaja :D

Comment: Gracias! +1 por tomarte el trabajo de arreglarlo.

Comment: No se puede como quieres. Aparte de lo que te sugirió abulafia, la otra opción sencilla es que tu menú principal tenga una opción 3 `Salir` y que haya un `(while opcion_menu != 3){` que haga que te repita el menú hasta que el usuario quiera salir. Estructura tus menús como los de los sistemas telefónicos, que siempre te dan la opción de devolverte al anterior, no te salgas de todo el programa desde una opción interior :)

Answer (score 1):

Y si haces esto?

```
case 1:
        cout <<"En este semestre se esta cursando actualmente 3 materias"<<endl;
        cout <<"Cada materia tiene un coste de: 50000"<<endl;
        cout <<"******************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Si desea calcular su promedio presione: "<<endl;
        cout<<"y"<<endl;
        cout<<"Si desea salir del programa presione: "<<endl;
        cout<<"n"<<endl;
        cin>>condicional;
        if (condicional =='n' || condicional != 'y'){
          break;
         }
       }
case 2:
```

De esta manera si se entra el programa sigue por case 2:, pero si entra una n u otra letra sale a la sentencia después del switch, donde puedes indicar que la opción no es válida por ejemplo.
También puedes meter la petición de respuesta en un bucle que solo acepte y o n. Si es n hace el break; y si no se lo salta y pasa a case2